# Recursive method for x to the power of y

Tags: java, recursion

I get 4 for 2,3. What would be causing this?

```
public static int basepowerexp(int base, int exp) {
    if (exp == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return base * basepowerexp(exp - 1, base);
    }
}

public static void bpe(int base, int exp) {
    System.out.println("The answer to " + base + " to the power of " + exp
            + " is " + power(base));
}
```

I think it's something to do with:

```
return base * basepowerexp(exp - 1, base);
```

But can't figure it out, I've tried other variations.

Comment: You reversed the exponent and the base in your recursive call.

Comment: the order of parameters is flipped in the call…

Comment: @rgettman even if I do, return base * basepowerexp(base-1,exp); I still get four as the answer.

Comment: @AdamHorrigan think about it. You don't decrement the base. You decrement the exponent. That's the very definition of exponentiation.

Comment: If you had used a debugger, it would have taken you a few seconds to find  your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the order of parameters in function call. this:

```
return base * basepowerexp(exp-1,base);
```

to this:

```
return base * basepowerexp(base, exp - 1);
```

But I'm wondering as you said you get 4 for 2,3! Because the answer will be 0 as I tested.

### Edit:

As you mentioned the problem exist yet, I'll put a working code as you can find the problem:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(basepowerexp(2, 3));
    }

    public static int basepowerexp(int base, int exp){
        if (exp == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return base * basepowerexp(base, exp - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Exactly this code, prints `8` for me.
Let me know if the problem exist.

Comment: This still gives me 4 for 2,3. In the main method, I run it like so: bpe(2,3);

Comment: I'll edit my answer and write the whole class with the methods and function calls, then you find the difference in it. ;)

Comment: Where I had  System.out.println("The answer to " +base+ " to the power of "+exp+ " is "+power(base,exp)); It should have been  System.out.println("The answer to " +base+ " to the power of "+exp+ " is "+basepowerexp(base,exp)); :)

Answer (score -1):

The base case should be reached when the exponent is 1. Have a look at my code.

```
public class test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Enter base;
        int base = in.nextInt();
        //Enter exponent
        int exp = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The answer to " + base + " to the power of "
            + exp + " is " + basepowerexp(base, exp));
    }

    public static int basepowerexp(int base, int exp) {
        if(exp >= 1)
            return base * basepowerexp(base, exp-1);
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```